# Como se puede hacer un WebView en Flet?

Tags: python, flutter, webview

Como pudiera hacerse un WebView en Flet para mostrar una página web en una misma venta del programa sin tener que abrir el navegador?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

crea un widget que contenga el webview

```
     class WebViewExample extends StatelessWidget {
       final String url;

        WebViewExample({required this.url});

        @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text('Ejemplo de WebView'),
        ),
        body: WebView(
        initialUrl: url,
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        ),
       );
      }
     }
```

utiliza el widget en tu body principal y le pasa la url